# Como limitar número de linhas SQL de acordo com uma variável?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma query SQL no PHP para pegar as informações de acordo com o número de linha de um arquivo inserido pelo usuário. Preciso pegar esse número de linhas de uma variável e e substituir pela variável no SQL.

Atualmente tenho esse codigo na função:

```
$conn = $this->connect();
    $sql =  " select * from requisicao r 
    inner join usuario u on r.id_requisitante = u.id_usuario 
    left join aprovador a   on a.id_aprovador = r.id_aprovador 
    left join categoria_requisicao cr on cr.id_cat_requisicao = r.id_cat_requisicao
    left join categoria c on  c.id_categoria = cr.id_categoria 
    left join sub_categoria_requisicao scr on scr.id_sub_cat_req = r.id_sub_cat_req
    left join sub_categoria sc on  sc.id_sub_categoria = scr.id_sub_categoria
    left join fornecedor_requisicao fr on fr.id_fornecedor_requisicao = r.id_fornecedor_requisicao
    left join fornecedor f on f.id_fornecedor = fr.id_fornecedor
    where r.id_requisitante = :id_usuario ORDER BY id_requisicao DESC limit :numeroL ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id_usuario', $id_usuario);
    $stmt->bindParam(':numeroL', $numeroL);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $result;
```

Mas dá um erro:

> Fatal error : Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: já tentou exibir como ficou a query em "$sql" e ver se tem algum erro, ou ainda pegar a query e tentar executar direto no banco? Pela mensagem a query ficou mal formada, pode ser na hora de substituir os parâmetros. De onde vem a variável `$numeroL`? coloque na sua pergunta

Comment: A query funciona no sql quando eu não coloco a variavel e coloco o proprio numero, quando eu tento pelo proprio mysql passar uma variavel da o mesmo erro. A variavel vem de uma outra função eu testei exibir ela e ta pegando o valor certo.

Comment: Verifique se os parâmetros `:id_usuario` e `:numeroL` estão com valores.  Observei que no `ORDER BY id_requisicao` o campo `id_requisicao` não aparece no restante da consulta, não deveria ser `ORDER BY r.id_requisitante`?

Answer (score -1):

1º Desative o `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`

O que evita que os valores passados ​​por `->execute([...])` sempre apareçam como strings.

```
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

2º O LIMIT obrigatóriamente precisa receber um INT como parâmetro

Tente alterar sua linha para:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':numeroL', intval($numeroL), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Para que o valor do LIMIT seja um inteiro.

Answer (score -3):

Se você quiser pegar algum campo de seu banco de dados deve fazer uma varável para receber o valor, por exemplo:

$var = 'select campoquerpegarodado from suatabela id_registro = 1 (deve saber qual é)

A partir desse momento, você tem a valor que quer na $var, agora na sua função deve
concatenar, por exemplo:

"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria=' { $var } '";.

Aí ao se registrar vai estar com o valor que quer substituir.

Comment: A variavel eu já estou pegando do proprio php, ela já pega o valor só que quando eu passo ela no "ORDER BY id_requisicao DESC limit :numeroL" da erro, fala que não pode passar variavel no desc limit